# XSS MySQL Database Accessible?

Tags: php, xss, known-vulnerabilities, sql-injection, mysql

I'd like to know if there is any danger of someone being able to access the database via XSS vulnerabilities on this page.

I have the following link. When you go to this link, the text I've enclosed as code displays on the site:
www.site.com/languages.php

```
{"languages":"
\n
<\/a><\/div>\n
English<\/div>\n <\/div>
\n
<\/a><\/div>\n
French<\/div>\n <\/div>
\n
<\/a><\/div>\n
German<\/div>\n <\/div>
<\/div>\n ","Russian":{"html":"
\n<\/a><\/div>","list":["57"]}}
```

I change the link to this and the text changes accordingly:
www.site.com/languages.php?list[]

```
{"languages":"
\n
<\/a><\/div>\n
English<\/div>\n <\/div>
\n
<\/a><\/div>\n
French<\/div>\n <\/div>
\n
<\/a><\/div>\n
German<\/div>\n <\/div>
<\/div>\n ","Russian":{"html":"
\n<\/a><\/div>","list":["","57"]}}
```

I again change the link and get this corresponding text:
www.site.com/languages.php?list[]=whatever

```
{"languages":"
\n
<\/a><\/div>\n
English<\/div>\n <\/div>
\n
<\/a><\/div>\n
French<\/div>\n <\/div>
\n
<\/a><\/div>\n
German<\/div>\n <\/div>
<\/div>\n ","Russian":{"html":"
\n<\/a><\/div>","list":["whatever","57"]}}
```

Yet again, I make the following change in the link and get the following on screen (whatever onwards is displayed in a red color):

```
www.site.com/languages.php?list[]=<font color=red>whatever</font>

{"languages":"
\n
<\/a><\/div>\n
English<\/div>\n <\/div>
\n
<\/a><\/div>\n
French<\/div>\n <\/div>
\n
<\/a><\/div>\n
German<\/div>\n <\/div>
<\/div>\n ","Russian":{"html":"
\n<\/a><\/div>","list":["whatever<\/font>","57"]}}
```

Comment: The first sentience has nothing to do with the rest of the information you have posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to access the database with XSS,  if an attacker delivers an XSS payload to a browser that has database access.  XSS allows an attacker to control a browser,  if that browser is an authenticated user then an attacker can carry out actions as that authenticated user.

Comment: Is it possible for someone to access my database based on the bulk of what I posted in my question--i.e. by appending something to the url (and what would that be called--SQLi?)?

Comment: @Pamela What on earth did you post?  Is that supposed to be XSS?  I don't see a script tag anywhere...  Regardless,  if it is XSS then my answer still stands.

Comment: maybe it's not XSS, but something else. In that case, I should rephrase my question--is there any danger of someone being able to access my database via ANY vulnerabilities on this page?

Comment: @Pamela I see a font tag,  but that is totally worthless.  Can you inject a script tag? Which would be Cross-site **scripting**.

Comment: Yes, I can inject a script tag.

Comment: @Pamela  Then yes,  XSS can be used to access the database if the browser executing the XSS payload can access the database. (Such as an administrator)

Comment: Would it also be possible to use SQLi for the purpose of accessing the database (instead of XSS)?

Comment: @Pamela the point of sqli is to obtain unauthorized access to the database.